# JxBrowser - From what version it does support WebGL?

Tags: jxbrowser

From what version JxBrowser does support WebGL? Is it possible to enable it in v6.14.2? I was searching references in official documentation but it seems to be missing in versions previous to 7.x.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WebGL is enabled in both JxBrowser 6 and 7.

If it doesn't work in 6.14.2, then it's probably due to the old and outdated Chromium 58 version used in JxBrowser 6.14.2. Some websites, including WebGL content, might not be compatible with Chromium 58 anymore. Please consider using the latest JxBrowser versions based on the latest Chromium builds.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work and I did a test in v7 using trial key and it worked. We are working on approvals to upgrade JXBrowser to latest version and upgrade application as well. Thank you!